# Hive script not running in crontab with hadoop must be in the path error

Tags: hive

After setting Hadoop Home path and Prefix path in .bashrc and /etc/profile also im getting the same error - **Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path**

If i run the script from crontab im facing this error from hive> prompt its working fine

plz help with the regarding how to solve this

Comment: how did you set path in your .batchrc file.can u post the command.

Comment: export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/opt/hadoop/hadoop                                    export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH                                                         this is how i kept my paths in .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Set $HADOOP_HOME in $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-env.sh

Comment: i added the paths in hive-env.sh also but still im getting the same error

Comment: Show me your hive-env.sh and crontab script.

Comment: Hi llobocki - after adding the hadoop path in hive/bin/hive-config.sh that error was solved thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try loading user bash profile in the script, as below,

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

bash is included in user bash_profile and it will have user specific configurations as well.

see the similar question [Hbase commands not working in script executed via crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510775/hbase-commands-not-working-in-script-executed-via-crontab/49511767#49511767)