# Hbase commands not working in script executed via crontab

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, cron, hbase

I was trying to list the set of tables present in the hbase using the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/user/hbase-1.2.4/bin/hbase shell << eof > /home/user/myfile.txt
list 'RAW_5_.*'
eof
```

I am able to get the table list while i run the script in the bash terminal using ::

> sh script.sh

, but its creating a 0kb file while running using the crontab. I have given the absolute path for the hbase.

Can anyone help on this bottleneck please?

Comment: Run without `sh` in command prompt and check what happened. just run as ./script.sh

Comment: its works that way too, in the command prompt. But while i schedule the same script via cron, i am not getting the table list.

Comment: Provide full file read write permission to your cron tab user.

Comment: The file writing directory has the full permissions for the user (where cron is scheduled). You can see am trying to write in the home directory of my user itself.

Comment: That is not enough. Provide access to `/home/user/` as well. That means user should have permission to do `cd /home/user/` as well.

Comment: Its there, the /home/user directory has `drwxrwxr-x` permissions for the "user"

Comment: OK, just check whether it has permission to execute `/home/user/hbase-1.2.4/bin/hbase`

Comment: it also has, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is executing properly from terminal and not in crontab, try loading user bash profile in the script instead of `#!/bin/bash` ie,

change

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Usually `#!/bin/bash` is included in `bash_profile` and it will have user specific configurations as well.